# Windows 10 freezes and becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-10-v1803

My Computer running on Windows 10 1803 keeps stuttering and freezing.
It basically becomes unresponsive for about a minute and then does everything you clicked while it was unresponsive very fast.
Example: I watch a youtube video. The video keeps playing and I cant pause nor close it. So I press CTRL+ALT+DEL to bring up the Task manager but nothing happens. After waiting a minute, the video stops, the task manager opens and everything works fine for about 10 minutes, then it happens again.
This happens on a fresh install of windows, regadless of if there are drivers installed or not.
Note: This doesnt happen on Linux, but I have to use Windows because my graphics tablet doesn't work properly with wine.
I noticed that Google Chrome always displays a small "Waiting for cache..." badge when this happens.

My System:
AMD FX-6300
MSI 1050ti 4GB
ASROCK Extreme3 990FX
16GB DDR3 RAM (reported fine with memtest)
120GB SATA3 SSD

---

EDIT
This problem occurs no matter how many or even if programs are opened or not.
The example also happens in Firefox

EDIT2
This problem has nothing to do with video playback or internet browsing, it alsdo happens when just using Word or playing games like osu!.

Comment: Your computer configuration is OK. Watching the video should be smooth. Does this situation just happened when you are watching youtube video? If so, just try to increase the cache of chrome and see whether the issue has been solved. If not, this may be some software occupy too much CPU resource. Use task manager and see what software occupy most resource when the situation occur.

Comment: @Peter.G There is no software occupying CPU resources when this problem occurs. Taskmanager says the CPU sits at around 10% or lower when this occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Are you watching a YouTube video in HD 1080P or higher?

If so, click the gear icon in the video turn the resolution down to 720p, or even the lowest setting.  Did the video stop stuttering?

If so, it could be Chrome's cache size.  Here is a decent [guide](https://appuals.com/how-to-speed-up-google-chrome/) on how to increase the cache size of Chrome for Windows.

Here are some other possible [solutions](https://blog.fonepaw.com/fix-choppy-video-on-chrome.html).

In addition to that, temporarily disable anything that hooks into the file system.  Disable any virus scanners and Windows Services like File History.  Improperly configured settings can significantly slow down Windows disk writes.  Which in turn, slow down high definition video.

Comment: My computer doesnt stutter while playing videos, not even of i set it to the highest possible resolution. Also, this happens with a clean windows installation, nothing, that hooks into the file system anywhere. I also tried disabling Windows Defender, but the problem still occurs.